# the concept of matrix transform

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

These statements are picked from *Intro to Linear Algebra 4th* by Strang

If we accpet this conception:
[image]

And an example[image]
$ v = [a \ b\ c\ d]^T = a*[1\ 0\ 0\ 0]^T +  b*[0\ 1\ 0\ 0]^T+  c*[0\ 0\ 1\ 0]^T + d*[0\ 0\ 0\ 1]^T $

So $\ v_3 = [0\ 0\ 1\ 0]^T $,

and $ w_2 = [ 0 \ 1 \ 0]^T$.

According the statement, $T(v_3) = a_{23}*w_2$, but it is obviously wrong.

There is another question: why is $T(v_j) $ is the comb. of $W$, I think $W$ is a comb. of $v$ ( linear combination)

Comment: $a_{23} = 2$?Right?@M.Vinay

Comment: $v_3$ is a basis vector , why do you multiply $v_3$ with a constant?

Comment: @M.Vinay Oh, I am sorry , I have edited my question

Comment: Okay, now $T(v_3) = T\begin{bmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\ 2\\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 2w_2$. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Er..? Yep, it is right... Maybe I calculate wrongly..@M.Vinay

Answer (score 1):

$T(v_j)$ is the projection of $v_j$ in $W$ space and columns of $W$ make the space $W$. So, $T(v_j)$, which is an element of the space $W$, is a combination of the matrix $W$.

about the first question, if you have a polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ choosing the coefficients using $[0,1,0,0]$ would give $x^2$ and the respective derivative (the actual transform)is $2x$ which corresponds to the vector $[0,2,0]$. so, I think you should do the calculation more carefully.

Comment: Actually, is the matrix called "transition matrix" which stands for the basis? Or it is just the coffeicient matrix? I am very confused..

Comment: well,I think, the term transition matrix is used when dealing with markov chains. In linear algebra it is usually called transformation matrix. It does not always correspond to a basis. it is only a function

Comment: Oh.. What is the relationship between transformation matrix and new/ old basis and new/ old vector?

Comment: put basis vectors of the first space in columns of a matrix and call it W. let T be the transformation matrix. TW would give you a new matrix. call it V. columns of V are vectors in the new space. depending on the transformation, the new matrix V may have dependent or independent columns.